# Swap background images on touch using phonegap?

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

Developing a mobile app with phonegap, i'm facing a small problem. When the touch presses any of my buttons I want to swap the background during the touch so I can give the user a visual feedback of what's going on.

But the onmousedown event is never fired in android, or any of the other events, except for onclick and onmouseup? How can I achieve that?

I have my javascript method to swap backgrounds that works.

```
function touched(isTouched){
                console.log(isTouched);
                if (isTouched) {
                    $('.blue_cell.firstCell').css("background-image", "url(images/cells/list-cell.png)");                   
                } else {
                    $('.blue_cell.firstCell').css("background-image", "url(images/cells/blue-cell.png)");
                }

            }
```

And I have my test button with the events I tried using:

```
<div class='blue_cell firstCell'  onmouseup="touched(false)" onmousedown="touched(true)"
        onmouseover="touched(true)" onfocusin="touched(true)">
    <div class='cellMainText'>openPopOver()</div>
    <div class='cellIconText'>POP</div></div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try ontouchstart and ontouchend

```
<div class='blue_cell firstCell' ontouchstart="javascript:alert()" ontouchend="javascript:alert()">
```

and see if the alerts fire.

Comment: Awesome! And I was working on some crazy workarounds with ISCROLL. Thanks a lot! Just out of curiosity do you have all of the usable events documented somewhere? I can't find any reference to ontouchstart/end. I'm beggining with javascript!

Comment: http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/webevents/raw-file/tip/touchevents.html#list-of-touchevent-types